# Postgres insert into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a SQL script like this which I run from the command line using `psql`:

```
insert into "A"."B" values
(1, 'name=a', 'a@example.com', 'K')
```

How do I convert it into `INSERT` command inside a database?

```
INSERT INTO "A"."B" (first_column, second_c, third_c, fourth_1) 
VALUES ('2', 'name=a', 'a@example.com.com', 'K');
```

Also what does `"A"."B"` do? I read somewhere that double quotes are needed when table name has Capitals. I seem to get an error with that when I run commands inside the database.

Comment: The names are missleading `"A"."first_column"` means:  a table named `first_column` in a schema named `"A"`

Comment: What do you mean with "convert inside a database"?

Comment: I am not exactly sure of the terminology, but when you connect to a particular DB using psql command and run commands there

Comment: You already **have** an `insert` statement, so what exactly are you trying to "convert"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that your database name was `DB` and your table name was `B`.

You can simply use the table name alone:

```
INSERT INTO "B" (first_column, second_c, third_c, fourth_1) 
VALUES ('2', 'name=a', 'a@example.com.com', 'K');
```

If you want to include the database name, then use:

```
INSERT INTO "DB"."B" (first_column, second_c, third_c, fourth_1) 
VALUES ('2', 'name=a', 'a@example.com.com', 'K');
```

The double quotes are only required when the name of any entity (e.g. table, column, etc...) is a reserved word.

Comment: `DB=> select * from "A"
DB->` I don't see anything

Comment: Database name is DB. How can I know the table name? His command did not throw any error, i made a mistake. But I don't see entries in the table like I do when I run the .sql scripts

Comment: Sorry I was confused. I am rolling back a change in my question. B is my table name. I made a dumb mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168180/discussion-between-pdna-and-racil-hilan).

Comment: Both the answers are correct, its just that I made a couple of typos in my commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query where A is schema and B is table name.

```
INSERT INTO "A"."B" (first_column, second_c, third_c, fourth_1) 
VALUES ('2', 'name=a', 'a@example.com.com', 'K');
```

Comment: After running this, when i run `select * from "A"."first_column";` i don't see the entry in the table.

Comment: This is identical to the query in the question. So how is this an answer?